# How to use Multiple list view in android?

Tags: android

I want to display three kind of different datas in list view.How to create a three list view and also how to implement in java code through Iconic Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this

```
  ArrayList<Object> routeList = getWmRoute();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> alist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i<routeList.size();i++){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("RetailerCode", ((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getDescription());
        map.put("RetailerName", ((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getBusinessUnit());
        alist.add(map);
    }

    ListView list= getListView();
    sd = new SimpleAdapter(this,alist,R.layout.retalier_rows,new String[]{"RetailerCode","RetailerName"},new int[]{R.id.retailerCode,R.id.retailerName});
    list.setAdapter(sd);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    list.setSelected(true);
    list.setSelection(0);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setItemChecked(positions,true);
```

and your xml file create(retalier_rows.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:text="RetailerCode" 
          android:id="@+id/retailerCode" 
          android:layout_width="125dp" 
          android:layout_height="35dp">
```

```
<TextView android:text="RetailerName" 
          android:layout_width="125dp" 
          android:layout_height="35dp"
          android:id="@+id/retailerName" 
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/retailerCode" 
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" 
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
```

If you need 3 column you can add it new  & code also can specify